# static and extern global variables in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, static, global-variables, extern

I made 2 projects, the first one in C and the second one in C++, both work with same behavior.

C project:

**header.h**

```
int varGlobal=7;
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

void function(int i)
{
    static int a=0;
    a++;
    int t=i;
    i=varGlobal;
    varGlobal=t;
    printf("Call #%d:\ni=%d\nvarGlobal=%d\n\n",a,i,varGlobal,t);
}

int main() {
    function(4);
    function(6);
    function(12);
    return 0;
}
```

C++ project:

**header.h**

```
int varGlobal=7;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

void function(int i)
{
    static int a=0;
    int t=i;
    a++;
    i=varGlobal;
    varGlobal=t;
    cout<<"Call #"<<a<<":"<<endl<<"i="<<i<<endl<<"varGlobal="<<varGlobal<<endl<<endl; 
}

int main() {
    function(4);
    function(6);
    function(12);
    return 0;
}
```

I read that global variables are **extern** by default and in C and **static** by default in C++; so why does the C++ code works?

I mean *int varGlobal=7;* is same as *static int varGlobal=7;* and if it's static then it can be used only in the file it was declared, right?

Comment: First note that `include` simply copy-pastes content. So for such single file example, it should be removed to simplify.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Global variables are not `extern` nor `static` by default on C and C++.
When you declare a variable as `static`, you are restricting it to the current source file. If you declare it as `extern`, you are saying that the variable exists, but are defined somewhere else, and if you don't have it defined elsewhere (without the `extern` keyword) you will get a link error (symbol not found).

Your code will break when you have more source files including that header, on link time you will have multiple references to `varGlobal`. If you declare it as `static`, then it will work with multiple sources (I mean, it will compile and link), but each source will have its own `varGlobal`.

What you can do in C++, that you can't in C, is to declare the variable as `const` on the header, like this:

```
const int varGlobal = 7;
```

And include in multiple sources, without breaking things at link time. The idea is to replace the old C style `#define` for constants.

If you need a global variable visible on multiple sources and not `const`, declare it as `extern` on the header, and then define it, this time without the extern keyword, on a source file:

Header included by multiple files:

```
extern int varGlobal;
```

In one of your source files:

```
int varGlobal = 7;
```

Comment: As I just discovered, there *is* a difference between C and C++ but it only applies to **const** objects: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fconst_cv_qualifier.htm

Comment: If you are going to put things in headers, some compilers/linkers will complain about multiply defined symbols.  Example: `const int varGlobal=7;`  Because you are declaring it `const` it can be treated as a global constant, but some compilers are not that smart.  What does work, always, is to declare things `static const` in the header file, like so: `static const int varGlobal = 7;`  That way even if the compiler is stupid, it won't add the symbol to the external symbols table and the linker will never see multiply defined symbols.

Comment: @steveha Declaring a constant as "static const" will cause annoying warnings on files that include the header, but do not use the constant (of course, depending on your compiler and warnings enabled).

Comment: @fbafelipe  That's right.  I forgot about it because there is usually a way to disable the warnings and I always use it.  For example, with GCC you can use `__attribute__ ((unused))` to disable that warning.  So I don't actually declare things `static const`, I declare them `LIBCONST` where `LIBCONST` is a `#define` macro I have made that declares `static __attribute__ ((unused))` for GCC, and just `static` for other platforms that don't warn.

Comment: By the way: the best reason to do this, instead of just using `#define`, is that when you are debugging the debugger can display the value of a constant.  With `#define` the constant is textually substituted in, so the name is gone and just the number is part of your program.  So if you used `#define` to define a constant `FOO`, you can't examine the value of `FOO` from the debugger; you must look it up in the source code.  But if you did `static const int FOO = 3;` in the header file, you can then examine `FOO` in the debugger and see that its value is 3.

Comment: Contrary to the opening line in this answer, in C, any variable or object declared outside of a function, and NOT declared static, is by default global and has extern scope. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03extsc.htm

Comment: +1 for `If you declare it as static, then it will work with multiple sources but each source will have its own varGlobal`

Comment: So, a variable marked as extern should never be initialized with a value, let's say `extern int x = 10;` it is not possible?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf If you want to initialize with a value, initialize in the c/cpp file, not the header. So in the header you have `extern int x;` and in the source file you have `int x = 10;`

Comment: From C++11 on you usually use `constexpr int constGlobal = 7;` to replace an old style `#define constGlobal = 7`. It is guaranteed to be a compile time constant (and can be used as template parameter, etc.), but still type safe.

Comment: @fbafelipe relatively good answer, only to be clear regarding "declare" vs. define, change your 2nd sentence to read:

" If you **declare** it as extern, you are saying that the variable exists, but is **defined** somewhere else, and if you don't have it **defined** elsewhere (without the extern keyword) you will get a link error (symbol not found)."

Also, very good that you brought out the point about "... but each source will have its own varGlobal" if "static" is used.

Answer (score 9):

When you `#include` a header, it's exactly as if you put the code into the source file itself. In both cases the `varGlobal` variable is defined in the source so it will work no matter how it's declared.

Also as pointed out in the comments, C++ variables at file scope are not static in scope even though they will be assigned to static storage. If the variable were a class member for example, it would need to be accessible to other compilation units in the program by default and non-class members are no different.

Comment: Also, the OP is incorrect in the assumption that globally declared variable are static by default in C++. They have external *linkage*, just as in C. Global variables have static *duration* in C and C++ though, so this can easily be confusing.

Comment: So the rule appllies for *.c an *.cpp files but not for *.h files? Thank you!

Comment: Another important thing: his code would break if he had multiple sources including that same header.