# Class member function accessing variable defined in main .cc file

Tags: c++, class, scope

Say I have a source file called main.cpp. Within this source file, I declare some variables outside the main() function. Then inside the main() function I call a class member function (which is properly declared and implemented in other .h and .cpp files) to assigns a value to one of the variables defined as outlined above (i.e. outside the main() function in main.cpp). When I do this it gives a "variable not defined in scope error". Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: use `extern T name` to declare a variable of type `T` that is located in another compilation unit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static and extern global variables in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055802/static-and-extern-global-variables-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Please just **don't use global variables.** No. Full stop. It's not good in C either, but in C++, it's even worse.