# Initialising a static map C++

Tags: c++

`Myfile.h`:

```cpp
namespace PredicateData {

using PredicateCallable = std::function<bool(char)>;

static enum class PredicateType {
    LOWER_CASE_ALPHABET = 2147483648,
    UPPER_CASE_ALPHABET = 1073741824,
    NUMBER = 536870912,
    SPACE = 268435456,
    SENTENCE_PUNCTUATION = 134217728,
    SPECIAL_CHARACTER = 67108864
};

using PredicateMap = std::unordered_map<PredicateType, PredicateCallable>;
static PredicateMap predicatemap;

static PredicateMap _InitPredicates() {
    PredicateMap tmp;
    //do something to tmp
    return tmp;
}

}
```

`Myfile.cpp`:

```cpp
PredicateData::PredicateMap PredicateData::predicatemap = _InitPredicates();
```

For some reason I get a compiler error: `'PredicateData::predicatemap': redefinition; multiple initialization`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielLangr What do you mean? Then how do I initialise it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static and extern global variables in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055802/static-and-extern-global-variables-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 1):

You should change `static` to `extern` in

```
static PredicateMap predicatemap;
```

It indicates to only declare the variable and tell the compiler it can find the definition in one of the compile units (possibly another one) which is "Myfile.cpp".

It becomes

```
extern PredicateMap predicatemap;
```

`static` keyword is used to limit the visibility of a class/function/variable/... to the current compile unit only.
This has no use in a header file which is meant for sharing declarations across your project. You should remove use  of `static` keyword in your header. It is probably not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing your `PrecicateData` *namespace* with a *class*. For the latter, you would declare a `static` member in the header and then (most likely) actually *define* it elsewhere (for example, in "MyFile.cpp"). However, for a `namespace`, data and functions are declared/defined in much the same way as for 'free' global variables.

So, either add the *definition* of your `predicatemap` in the header, like this (you will, of course, need to place it *after* the definition of `_InitPredicates`):

```cpp
namespace PredicateData {
    using PredicateCallable = std::function<bool(char)>;
    enum class PredicateType {
        LOWER_CASE_ALPHABET = 2147483648,
        UPPER_CASE_ALPHABET = 1073741824,
        NUMBER = 536870912,
        SPACE = 268435456,
        SENTENCE_PUNCTUATION = 134217728,
        SPECIAL_CHARACTER = 67108864
    };
    using PredicateMap = std::unordered_map<PredicateType, PredicateCallable>;
    static PredicateMap _InitPredicates()
    {
        PredicateMap tmp;
        //do something to tmp
        return tmp;
    }
    static PredicateMap predicatemap = _InitPredicates();
}
```

Or, alternatively, declare `predicatemap` as `extern`:

```cpp
namespace PredicateData {
    using PredicateCallable = std::function<bool(char)>;
    enum class PredicateType {
        LOWER_CASE_ALPHABET = 2147483648,
        UPPER_CASE_ALPHABET = 1073741824,
        NUMBER = 536870912,
        SPACE = 268435456,
        SENTENCE_PUNCTUATION = 134217728,
        SPECIAL_CHARACTER = 67108864
    };
    using PredicateMap = std::unordered_map<PredicateType, PredicateCallable>;
    extern PredicateMap predicatemap;
    static PredicateMap _InitPredicates()
    {
        PredicateMap tmp;
        //do something to tmp
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

and then provide the *definition* in your source file (but note, you will also need to add the `PredicateData::` namespace to the `_InitPredicates()` function):

```cpp
PredicateData::PredicateMap PredicateData::predicatemap = PredicateData::_InitPredicates();
```

Also note that the use of `static` before `enum class` is not permitted (I have removed it in the code samples above).